# Logins for Winform Application used by multiple users

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, security

My Winform Application uses SQL SERVER & is used to insert data into a database & is used by three users.

All 3 Users are on LAN & only one PC is having sql server, the others connect to it.

each user would be having different privileges on the database.

LoginA would CREATE LoginB & LoginC with some passwords.

i have given one SQL SERVER Login to each user.

Using these Logins, each user connects to SQL SERVER & starts inserting the data into the database.
I want that each user when opens the application, is asked to enter the credentials.
Is this an efficient method (i.e. giving separate sql server logins to each user) or i shall use application roles & let LoginA create Application Roles with some passwords for LoginB and LoginC?

or shall i use something else?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Authentication seems to be a better solution here since all users are in the internal network, instead of creating logins with passwords.
Just create logins referencing windows users or windows groups.
This way users are not asked for a password and the credentials used to log into the computer are automatically used to access SQL Server.

Comment: @Arturo: if i use Windows Authentication, and if the PC was left ON by the correct user , then any illegal person would come and open the application and would be directly connected to the database as there is no way to prompt for the password . in this case what would you refer?

Comment: The same thing would happen if the user logs in with SQL Auth and leaves Windows unlocked.

Comment: no , the user had closed the application but the pc was left ON. so when a wrong user comes he simply opens and is automatically connected to sql server.  but when i use logins then i prompt for loginid and password  every time the application is opened

Comment: I Always go with Windows Authentication. The purpose of Windows Authentication is to eliminate the need for many usernames and passwords inside the organization for multiple internal appplications. Yo can still challenge the user to verify their windows credentials before using the program.
VALUE -> A single username and password and not multiple sticky notes on their monitors.

Comment: so if the application is opened , then can i prompt the user for password when i use windows authentication

Comment: Also it would be a good idea in your organization to implement GPO rules to automatically lock the computers after some time of inactivity.

Comment: Correct, You dont make available any functionality unless they verify Windows Credentials. Take a look at System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Comment: This [article](http://smartypeeps.blogspot.com/2006/12/validate-windows-domain-account-in-c.html) can help too.

Comment: so , to force the user enter the login and password which he used for logging on the PC, can be asked also when the winform application is opened, but by using C#.NET. sql server doesn't allows this functionality, but in the case of SQL SERVER Logins , if a wrong login is supplied , then its the duty of sql server to deny that login to enter.

Comment: please tell me the disadvantages or drawbacks if i stick to using Separate Sql Server Logins for each user.

Comment: What you are saying is correct. SQL Server knows who has access to what. If a user opens the program with other credentials than the ones SQL Server knows have permission, any action (insert, query, execute or whatever you define) the user will be denied access to those actions. It works just the way any SQL login would work. The disadvantage of using Separate SQL Login is that user need to remember an extra set of credentials. One day they forget or confuse with their windows credential and their you go again trying to fix what you user calls a program error.

Comment: As applications grow and the need to have more people working on an application you need to add all those logins. I prefer to just add the new users to a AD Windows Group all the users that need access and register these groups in SQL Server. You can define as many Windows Groups as you want depending on the access levels you need in SQL Server.

Comment: This is one of the main reasons why Microsoft added Windows Authentication support in SQL Server. (Centralized Management).
You dont want to have all your users in AD and also a different login for SQL Server. Make use of the great infrastructure you already have in place (Active Directory)

Comment: Another example would be. Lets say you have to let an employee go. You disable this user in AD and automatically SQL Server knows the user is not allowed any actions in the network. With a SQL Login you have to remove permission in 2 places (AD and SQL). There are many examples of why Windows Authentication just makes sense.

Comment: I would recommend for you to plan the Access Levels you want for you application and after that you can ask IT to add Windows Groups in Active Directory that resemble those levels. Use these groups in SQL Server and then as Users come and go they need to be added or removed from those groups in AD.

Comment: @Arturo: thanks a lot for your great helping replies sir, also , when three pcs are on LAN , then is there Active Directory?

Comment: @Arturo: i am not familiar with Active Directory, i can guess that in Internet Cafes , it can be used, where the cafe owner would like to keep watch on the other pcs on which customers come and surf. am i right sir?

Comment: Is this application for an Internet Cafe?

Comment: no no, sir, my application is for medical stores, and other retailers and wholesalers of multiple confectionery products

Answer (score 1):

Using Application roles is recommended since it shall not effect the the application in anyway if the userbase is increased and would be much more manageable.